# Round Robin simulation in real processes with java

Tags: java, process, round-robin

I want to implement RR algorithm in java. But I want the processes to be real, supose I have some other programs in java and I call them in this algorithm to be executed. But how can I do this by "wanting" the CPU in the same time all processes? Then I want to know the CPU usage from these processes.

Comment: Java is not capable of doing some of those thigs, it's just a too high-level language for that.

Comment: really? What about c language, is it convenient for this?